# Group multiple entries by a column in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of records I am showing in a table within a view file that looks as follows:

```
|| user || sport || # of victories || # of losses ||  
|| Jane || foo   ||       1        ||      1      ||  
|| Jane || foo   ||       2        ||      3      ||  
|| Jane || bar   ||       1        ||      1      ||  
|| Jane || bar   ||       2        ||      3      ||
```

In the example above, I am trying to group the results based on the sport, so rather than having the 2 records

```
|| Jane || foo   ||       1        ||      1      ||  
|| Jane || foo   ||       2        ||      3      ||
```

There would be a single grouping, which is currently broken up into multiple entries based on another column I'm not displaying on this view.

```
|| Jane || foo   ||       3        ||      4      ||
```

I've been trying .group and .group_by to accomplish this, but don't seem to be doing this correctly. Can someone please provide some pointers?

Additional info, if needed:

Table schema

```
create_table "records", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
 t.integer "victories"
 t.integer "losses"
 t.bigint "user_id"
 t.bigint "sport_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "opposition_id"
 t.index ["opposition_id"], name: "index_records_on_category_id"
 t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_records_on_user_id"
end
```

Controller

```
  def board
    @summary = Record.all.sort_by{ |i| i.user_id }
  end
```

View

```
   <% @summary.each do |record| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= record.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= record.sport_id %></td>
      <td><%= record.victories %></td>
      <td><%= record.losses %> </td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a query, just as example I placed all in the view, but use the controller to fetch data.

```
<% sport_records = SportRecord.group(:user_id).select(:user_id, :sport_id, "sum(victories) as total_victories", "sum(losses) as total_losses") %>
<% sport_records.each do |sr| %>
  <p><%= sr.sport.name %> | <%= sr.user.name %> | <%= sr.total_victories %> | <%= sr.total_losses %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you also need to group by sport, change into

```
SportRecord.group(:user_id, :sport_id).select(:user_id, :sport_id, "sum(victories) as total_victories", "sum(losses) as total_losses")
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks @iGian